# How to combine NOT filter in MS Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to search graph API users for everyone whos name does **not** start with some value

I tried

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter="NOT startswith(displayName,'J')"
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=not(startswith(displayName,'J'))
```

But I get

> Invalid filter clause

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

I actually need to do this in C#, where I run into the same issue - I wonder if there is a way of specifying `NOT STARTSWITH` using the SDK?

```
string filter = String.Format("startswith(displayName,'J')");
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
    new QueryOption("$filter", filter)
};
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request(options)
    .Top(500)
    .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this type of filter is not supported by `users` (or any other Azure AD resources). From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#format-parameter):

> The following `$filter` operators are not supported for Azure AD resources:  `ne`, `gt`, `ge`, `lt`, `le`, and `not`.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Do you happen to know what the performance implications would be for writing a filter which searches for users whos name `startswith` **every character except for the one I need to exclude**? E.g. `startswith(displayName,'A') OR startswith(displayName,'B') OR startswith(displayName,'C')..` etc (it would just contain each letter of the alphabet, so 26 `startswith`s

Comment: It would seem far more performant to just pull the entire list and then filter on the client side (i.e. `Linq` against the `Users` collection).

Answer (score 1):

Its not users, but i managed to get data with `not startsWith` like this:

`client.DeviceManagement.ManagedDevices.Request().Filter("not startsWith(operatingSystem, 'Windows')").GetAsync()`