# Graph API: is logical negation "NOT" not supported in $filter?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, outlook-api

The Graph API for messages states that 'NOT' is supported in filters:

> Support for $filter operators varies across Microsoft Graph APIs. The
> following logical operators are generally supported:
>
> equals (eq) in (in) not equals (ne) greater than (gt) greater than or
> equals (ge) less than (lt), less than or equals (le) and (and) or (or)
> not (not)

And yet a simple request to find messages with "$filter=not startswith(subject,'text')" fails:

> "error": {
> "code": "BadRequest",
> "message": "Filter not supported.",
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2020-08-06T17:53:27",
> "request-id": "a885e3e3-1c9f-476c-9c5c-9951abf601a8"
> }   }

Is this an API bug?

Another issue with the docs, contains(prop,'text') actually works fine for messages!

> The contains string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

But we really need to use NOT and I believe it worked in the past.

Comment: Is this going to be fixed any time soon? Not supporting NOT seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Am also stuck around this. Seems NOT operator is not supported by Microsoft Graph API however there is no such mention in the documentation. It seems there is already a thread on this: [How to combine NOT filter in MS Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197733/how-to-combine-not-filter-in-ms-graph-api)

I am not sure if its going to be supported in the future.

Comment: I am almost sure this used to work a few months ago. I think something in Graph API broke and is not getting fixed.